# HTML Searchbar's Styles Changing Onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, searchbar

This is probably a very big oversight on my end, but I have added a search-bar to my website, and when you click it, the border style changes to a black and white border, I don't want it to do that. I would like the border to stay the same on click of the search-bar. Thanks.

```js
let searchBar = document.querySelector('.searchBar');
let alertOnce = 0;

searchBar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alertOnce++;
  
  if (alertOnce == 1) {
    alert("note, you can't have multiple words.")
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="" class="searchBar" />
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as, I understood your problem,
To prevent the changing border style on clicking on the input field, you can set [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) css property to `none`.

**#css**

```
input {
   outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

And when `outline` is set to `none`

```css
input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: Since this has been answered somewhere else should I delete the question? Also thank you!